# Modulo operations in octave

Tags: octave

I have to calculate mod$(2^{1000-k},8k+1)$ (k≤50)with octave. How can I do that? $2^{1000}$ is too big...

I think I can split the modulo operation but the code becomes heavy. Is there a way to set octave to manage these huge number?

Comment: $2^{1000}$ is actually a pretty small number as far as multiprecision arithmetic goes.

Answer (score 2):

Edit: (thanks to Anonymous' suggestion):

To compute $$2^{1000-k} \mod 8k+1.$$

We do not need to compute the value of $2^{1000-k}$ explicitly.

In fact, we can use the properties that $$(ab \mod c) = (a \mod c)( b \mod c)$$

Looping through $1000-k$ is manageable for a computer.

You just have to repeatedly multiply by $2$ and take modulo $8k+1$ for $1000-k$ times.

I have attached a code in [Python.](http://www.codeskulptor.org/#user43_lBdxQ1s5wcbMmPS.py)

A faster approach would be  [exponentiation by squaring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring) which makes use of the idea that

$$x^n = \begin{cases} x(x^2)^{\frac{n-1}{2}} & n \text{ is odd} \\  (x^2)^{\frac{n}{2}} & n \text{ is even}\end{cases}$$

Comment: I think a more helpful (for him) answer would be to tell him that $a\cdot b \mod c = (a\mod c \cdot b \mod c )\mod c$ and for that reason he can applies modulo at every iteration (extending the relation to any amount of  elements)

Comment: and for this reason he doesn't need to evalue $2^{1000}$ first, which I intuitively think is the point in which he struggles.

Comment: Wonderful suggestion. =)

Comment: I say this because he said "$2^{1000}$ is too big"

Comment: To compute the requested Power One will use the  pow(x,y,z) function in python: pow (2,1000-k, 8*k+1), wich does  fast modular exponentiation. But I dont  know if there is a similar function in octave.